# How to understand the difference between class_eval() and instance_eval()?

Tags: ruby, class-method, instance-method

```
Foo = Class.new
Foo.class_eval do
  def class_bar
    "class_bar"
  end
end
Foo.instance_eval do
  def instance_bar
    "instance_bar"
  end
end
Foo.class_bar       #=> undefined method ‘class_bar’ for Foo:Class
Foo.new.class_bar   #=> "class_bar"
Foo.instance_bar       #=> "instance_bar"
Foo.new.instance_bar   #=> undefined method ‘instance_bar’ for #<Foo:0x7dce8>
```

Just based on the name of the methods, **I would expect class_eval to allow you to add a class method to Foo and instance_eval to allow you to add an instance method to Foo. But they seem to do the opposite**.

In the example above if you call class_bar on the Foo class you get an undefined method error and if you call instance_bar on the instance returned by Foo.new you also get an undefined method error. Both errors seem to contradict an intuitive understanding of what class_eval and instance_eval should do.

**What is really the difference between these methods?**

Documentation for [class_eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/classes/Module.html#M001673):

> mod.class_eval(string [, filename [,
>   lineno]]) => obj
>
> *Evaluates the string or block in the
>   context of mod. This can be used to
>   add methods to a class.*

Documentation for [instance_eval](http://www.rubybrain.com/api/ruby-1.8.7/doc/index.html?a=M000295&name=instance_eval):

> obj.instance_eval {| | block } => obj
>
> *Evaluates a string containing Ruby
>   source code, or the given block,
>   within the context of the receiver
>   (obj). In order to set the context,
>   the variable self is set to obj while
>   the code is executing, giving the code
>   access to obj’s instance variables.*

Answer (score 118, accepted):

As the documentation says, `class_eval` evaluates the string or block in the context of the Module or Class.  So the following pieces of code are equivalent:

```
class String
  def lowercase
    self.downcase
  end
end

String.class_eval do
  def lowercase
    self.downcase
  end
end
```

In each case, the String class has been reopened and a new method defined.  That method is available across all instances of the class, so:

```
"This Is Confusing".lowercase 
=> "this is confusing"
"The Smiths on Charlie's Bus".lowercase
=> "the smiths on charlie's bus"
```

`class_eval` has a number of advantages over simply reopening the class.  Firstly, you can easily call it on a variable, and it's clear what your intent is.  Another advantage is that it will fail if the class doesn't exist.  So the example below will fail as `Array` is spelt incorrectly.  If the class was simply reopened, it would succeed (and a new incorrect `Aray` class would be defined):

```
Aray.class_eval do
  include MyAmazingArrayExtensions
end
```

Finally `class_eval` can take a string, which can be useful if you're doing something a little more nefarious...

`instance_eval` on the other hand evaluates code against a single object instance:

```
confusing = "This Is Confusing"
confusing.instance_eval do
  def lowercase
    self.downcase
  end
end   

confusing.lowercase
=> "this is confusing"
"The Smiths on Charlie's Bus".lowercase
NoMethodError: undefined method ‘lowercase’ for "The Smiths on Charlie's Bus":String
```

So with `instance_eval`, the method is only defined for that single instance of a string.

So why does `instance_eval` on a `Class` define class methods?

Just as `"This Is Confusing"` and `"The Smiths on Charlie's Bus"` are both `String` instances, `Array`, `String`, `Hash` and all other classes are themselves instances of `Class`.  You can check this by calling `#class` on them:

```
"This Is Confusing".class
=> String

String.class
=> Class
```

So when we call `instance_eval` it does the same on a class as it would on any other object.  If we use `instance_eval` to define a method on a class, it will define a method for just that instance of class, not all classes.  We might call that method a class method, but it is just an instance method for that particular class.

Comment: This is a terrific explanation. Thanks. I followed you all the way up until the last paragraph where you try to explain why instance_eval defines class methods when called on a Class. The last line is particularly difficult for me to digest: "Calling it a class method is a mistake, it's just an instance method on that particular Class instance." Do you mean that all class methods are nothing more than that?

Comment: Yeah, exactly - that's all they are.  I will try and make it clearer tomorrow.

Comment: Fantastic - I just added a new question specifically for that issue: "Why does instance_eval() define a class method when called on a class?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900704/why-does-instanceeval-define-a-class-method-when-called-on-a-class.

Answer (score 23):

The other answer is correct, but allow me to go in depth a little.

Ruby has a number of different kinds of scope; six according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29#Features), though detailed formal documentation seems to be lacking. The kinds of scope involved in this question are, not surprisingly, **instance** and **class**.

The current instance scope is defined by the value of `self`. All unqualified method calls are dispatched to the current instance, as are any references to instance variables (which look like `@this`).

However, `def` is not a method call. The target for methods created by `def` is the current class (or module), which can be found with `Module.nesting[0]`.

Let's see how the two different eval flavors affect these scopes:

`String.class_eval { [self, Module.nesting[0]] }
  => [String, String]
String.instance_eval { [self, Module.nesting[0]] }
  => [String, #<Class:String>]`

In both cases, the instance scope is the object on which *_eval is called.

For `class_eval`, the class scope also becomes the target object, so `def` creates instance methods for that class/module.

For `instance_eval`, the class scope becomes the **singleton class** (aka metaclass, eigenclass) of the target object. Instance methods created on the singleton class for an object become singleton methods for that object. Singleton methods for a class or module are what are commonly (and somewhat inaccurately) called **class methods**.

The class scope is also used to resolve constants. Class variables (`@@these @@things`) are resolved with class scope, but they skip over singleton classes when searching the module nesting chain. The only way I have found to access class variables in singleton classes is with `class_variable_get/set`.

Comment: +1 for also introducing scope here, in addition to only self by other answers.

Comment: Great answer. Out of curiosity, is there any substitute for `Module.nesting[0]` since it does not seem to work this way in recent ruby versions?

Answer (score 4):

I think you got it wrong. class_eval adds the method in the class, so all instances will have the method. instance_eval will add the method just to one specific object.

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.instance_eval do
  def instance_bar
    "instance_bar"
  end
end

foo.instance_bar      #=> "instance_bar"
baz = Foo.new
baz.instance_bar      #=> undefined method
```

Comment: You're calling instance_eval on the object foo while I'm calling it on the class Foo. I don't see how this relates.

Answer (score 3):

instance_eval effectively creates a singleton method for the object instance in question. class_eval will create a normal method in the given class's context, available to all objects of that class.

Here's a link regarding [singleton methods](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/singletonmethods.html) and the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)(non-ruby specific)

Answer (score 1):

`instance_eval` and `class_eval` allow you to execute a chunk of code. So what you might say? The old-fashioned `eval` can do this. But `instance_eval` and `class_eval` accept a block argument for the chunk of code. So the chunk of code does not need to be a string. Also `instance_eval` and `class_eval` allow a receiver (unlike the old `eval`). Consequently, you can invoke these two modern methods on a class object or even on an instance object.

```
class A
end

A.instance_eval do
  # self refers to the A class object
  self
end

a = A.new

a.instance_eval do
  # self refers to the a instance object
  self
end
```

Also remember in ruby if we call a method without a receiver, then the method would be invoked on `self`, which in the `instance_eval` block is the object we invoked `instance_eval` on. instance variables are private in ruby. You cannot access them outside the class they are defined in. But since instance variables are stored in `self`, we can access them in `instance_eval` (the same applies for private methods which cannot be invoked with a receiver):

```
class A
  def initialzie
    @a = “a”
  end

  private

  def private_a
    puts “private a”
  end
end

a = A.new
puts a.instance_eval {  @a }
# => “a”
puts a.instance_eval {  private_a }
# => “private a”
```

We can also add methods to the receiver in `instance_eval` and `class_eval`. Here we add it to `instance_eval`:

```
class A
end

A.instance_eval do
  def a_method
    puts “a method”
  end
end

A.a_method
# =>  a method
```

Now think what we just did for a moment. We used `instance_eval`, defined a method in its `block`, and then invoked the method on the class object itself. Isn’t that a class method? Think of it as a “class” method if you want. But all we did was define a method on the receiver in the `instance_eval` block, and the receiver happened to be `A`. We can easily do the same on a instance object:

```
 a.instance_eval do
  def a_method
    puts "a method"
  end
end

a.a_method
# => a method
```

And it works just the same. Don’t think of class methods as class methods in other languages. They are just methods defined on `self`, when `self` happens to be a class object (extending from `Class.new` as in `class A end`).

But I want to take this answer a little bit more deeper than the accepted answer. Where does `instance_eval` actually stick the methods you place into them? They go into the `singleton` class of the receiver! As soon as you invoke `instance_eval` on the receiver, the ruby interpreter opens the `singleton_class` and places the methods defined in the block inside this `singleton_class`. It is just like using `extend` in a class (because extend opens up the singleton class and places the methods in the module passed to extend into the singleton class)! It opens up the `singleton_class`, which is part of the inheritance hierarchy (right before the parent class): `A -> singleton_class -> Parent`

Now what makes `class_eval` different? `class_eval` can only be called on classes and modules. `self` still refers to the receiver:

```
class A
end

A.class_eval do
  # self is A
  self
end
```

But unlike `instance_eval`, when you define methods in the `class_eval` block, they will be available on instances of the class not the class object itself. With `class_eval`, the methods are not added to the singleton class in the inheritance hierarchy. Instead the methods are added to the `current class` of the receiver! So when you define a method in `class_eval`, that method goes directly into the `current class` and, thus, it becomes an instance method. So you cannot call it on the class object; you can only call it on instances of the class object.