# instance_eval, define_method and method_missing

Tags: ruby

guys. I create a class:

```
class A
  def initialize &b
    instance_eval &b
  end

  def method_missing method_id, *args
    self.define_method(method_id) { puts args.first }
  end
end

b = A.new { new_method "oops" }
```

But is does not work

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

Why?

Comment: you could add a trace or a breakpoint in method_missing and try to figure yourself what the problem is ...

Comment: When adding some log statements to your code, you will see that define_method is not defined for the instance, therefore the recursion. When adding `p "Begin method_missing for #{method_id}"` before calling the define_method, you will get logged a lot of lines: `Begin method_missing for define_method`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

define_method is not defined for an **instance** of A, so when you call self.define_method that cal method_missing again, an again => stack overflow.

You need to do something like that instead

```
class A
     def initialize &b
       instance_eval &b
     end

     def method_missing(method_id, *args)
       self.class.instance_eval do
         define_method(method_id) { debugger; puts args.first }
       end
     end
   end
```

Comment: you can have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900419/how-to-understand-the-difference-between-class-eval-and-instance-eval)

Comment: @avy it might be safer for these methods to be added as singleton methods (e.g. it's thread-safe). Do you really need the method added for every instance?