# class_eval and open classes

Tags: ruby, spree

I am using Spree, and Spree has a class called `Order` that looks like:

```
module Spree
  class Order
    # class definition.
  end
end
```

In my own app, I have been customising `Order` like so:

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  # customisations
end
```

My question is, can I simply just do this:

```
module Spree
  class Order
    # My own customisations.
  end
end
```

Any downsides to this? Essentially, I want to avoid using `class_eval`.

Comment: hey.. did you find a solution to this? I'm now just getting started with spree, and need to add a constant to the Spree::Order class. using `class_eval` somehow isn't working for constants, and without class_eval, I can't figure out how to access other methods in the class that I am reopening.

Comment: Try using `@@some_constant`. Not a Spree issue, but a general Ruby weirdness.

Comment: yep.. that's what I did and it worked. One note though, I had to `require` the module/class that I was opening prior to opening it. This ensured that the original class file was loaded before I opened it again to change it to avoid getting class not found errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Benjamin, reopen class will not inform you (but `class_eval` will raise error) if the existing class does not exist or not loaded.

But if you have test coverage, reopen class should be safe I guess?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/900508/474597 for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Ah good point. I'm in the process of _existing_ `class_eval`ed classes.

Answer (score 0):

you cant alter the class without class_eval. 
just try to override one method, and all other methods are gone. with class_eval you avoid it. thats the ruby way.

Comment: @raj englighten me!

Comment: How does opening a class and over riding a method remove all other methods? Can you show an example?

Comment: maybe you're right. can't remember.

might be rails specfic. in rails you need to use class_eval, otherwise the initial class evaportaes.

Comment: The initial class would never evaporate if you reopen a class in rails. Can you show me any example resource ? I couldnt find any.

Comment: i don't need any resource. that's just how rails is working. might has to do with its internal cache_classes ?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to solve this problem, which works quite well in the case of Spree.  I thought I'd leave this answer for others working with Spree.

You can use `prepend` in order to 'schedule' the class reopening at whatever time that Spree is finally loaded.

```rb
module Spree
  # Decorates Spree::Order
  module OrderDecorator
    CANCELLATION_STATES = %w[canceled pre_canceled].freeze

    def self.prepended(base)
      base.belongs_to :delivery, class_name: 'Delivery', foreign_key: 'delivery_id', optional: true
      base.scope :deliverable, lambda { }
    end
  end
end

Spree::Order.prepend Spree::OrderDecorator
```

If your decorator modules gets too many methods, you can and should use multiple and control the prepend order.

```rb
Spree::Order.prepend Spree::OrderDecorator
Spree::Order.prepend Admin::SpreeOrderAdminable
```