# Understanding Simple `instance_eval` Example

Tags: ruby

Looking at this [instance_eval](http://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/instance_eval) example:

```
class KlassWithSecret
    def initialize
        @secret = 99
    end
    def get
        @secret
    end
end
k = KlassWithSecret.new
k.instance_eval { @secret } 
print k.get
```

I added a `get` method to `KlassWithSecret`.

Here's the results of running the program:

```
>ruby InstanceEvalTest.rb
99
```

So, does `instance_eval` here somehow call the `initialize` method?

I think that I understand this method a bit from reading this helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/900508/409976). But I'm still in the dark.

Comment: so, in this example, `instance_eval` is not doing anything with `@secret`, no? I'm trying to understand why, in this example, `@secret` is passed in.

Comment: @cary can you answer the question, not put the comments here? Seems your explanation is better than August.

Comment: You asked me to put my comments in the form of an answer. I said I'd do that the following day, but forgot to do so so. It's now done--sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2):

The `initialize` method is automatically called by Ruby after the `new` method is called. `instance_eval` runs the block you supply in the *context of the object*. This means it has access to anything a normal line of code in the `KlassWithSecret` class would have.

`@secret` is an *instance variable*, meaning that it belongs to an instance of `KlassWithSecret`. Because we're evaluating `{ @secret }` in the context of a `KlassWithSecret` instance, we can access `@secret`.

Answer (score 2):

`k.instance_eval` gives you access to all of the instance variables (here just `@secret`) and all private methods (if there were any). It executes the code in the block, which in this case returns `99`, the value of `@secret`. Then `print k.get` prints that value and returns `nil`.

If the block had been `{ @secret = 'cat' }`, `k.instance_val` would have changed the value of `@secret` (and returned the new value).

When using `instance_eval`, `class_eval`, `class < self` and other metaprogramming constructs, you mind find it helpful to track the value of `self` using `puts` statements. For example:

```
k = KlassWithSecret.new #=> #<KlassWithSecret:0x00000101897810 @secret=99>
self #=> main
k.instance_eval { puts "self=#{self}"; @secret }
"self=#<KlassWithSecret:0x00000101897810>"
  #=> 99
```