# Ruby Module can't access local variable

Tags: ruby, scope

Is there anyway to access `foo` from `GetVar.print_foo`?

```
foo = "test"

module GetVar
    def self.print_foo
        puts foo
    end
end

GetVar.print_foo
```

I was able to get it to work by changing `foo` to a constant `FOO`, but this is more of a hack and I am looking for a better solution. I also can't, or rather prefer not, to make `foo` an instance variable `@foo`.

Comment: You could add  `def self.foo; "test"; end` inside the module.

Comment: @CarySwoveland no, its cause I am not defining foo - which is actually 'verify_recaptcha', it is coming from another gem. I am using the recaptcha gem and I am trying to create a helper method that calls `verify_recaptcha`, but the helper function creates a new scope that does not have the function I need from the recaptcha gem.

Comment: @ChristianJuth A local variable is local to the current call to a method, or local to the top level binding if you define that in the top level. It cannot and should not be accessed anywhere else.

Comment: @ChristianJuth Your problem sounds like a design problem, so can you ask another question about your real problem?

Comment: @ChristianJuth : Technically, you could make *foo* a global variable (`$foo`), but don't do that unless you have very good reason to do so. As Aetherus said, this looks more like a design problem to me.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: no, there is no way to access the local variable `foo` in the script scope from the method scope of the `print_foo` method. `foo` is a local variable, local variables are local to the scope they are defined in, that's why they are called "local" variables, after all.

`foo` is defined in the script scope. It is not defined in the method scope of `print_foo`, ergo, it cannot be accessed from `print_foo`.

There are four local variable scopes in Ruby: script, module / class definition, method definition, and lambda literal / block body. Of these four, script scope, module / class scope, and method scope create new scopes. Lambda literals and blocks, and *only* those two create nested scopes that can access local variables from their surrounding lexical scopes.

So, the only way to get access to `foo` in `print_foo` is to make sure that `print_foo` is defined in a nested scope, i.e. in a block, and that all the surrounding scopes are also blocks. Thankfully, there is a method for defining methods called [`Module#define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-define_method) (or in this case actually [`Object#define_singleton_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method)) that takes a block, and there is a method for defining a module called [`Module::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-c-new) that also takes a block:

Is there anyway to access `foo` from `GetVar.print_foo`?

```
foo = "test"

GetVar = Module.new do 
  define_singleton_method(:print_foo) do puts foo end
end

GetVar.print_foo
# test
```

Actually, we don't even need the block form of `Module::new`:

```
foo = "test"

GetVar = Module.new.tap do |m| m.define_singleton_method(:print_foo) do puts foo end end

GetVar.print_foo
# test
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `class_eval`

```
class A
  @foo = "test"
end
module GetVar
  def self.print_foo
      A.class_eval do
        puts @foo
      end
  end
end
GetVar.print_foo
#=> "test"
```

or flattening the scope

```
foo = "test"
GetVar = Module.new do
  # define a class method
  define_singleton_method :print_foo do
    puts foo
  end
end
GetVar.print_foo
#=> "test"
```

See this question: [How to understand the difference between class_eval() and instance_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900419/how-to-understand-the-difference-between-class-eval-and-instance-eval)