# Ruby idiom: pattern for installing `acts_as` behavior without the need of nested methods (like in the Paranoia gem)

Tags: ruby

I was digging through the [Paranoia gem](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia/blob/core/lib/paranoia.rb) to understand how it achieved the effect of overriding the default scope of the models it's used in.

To my surprise, I found out a pattern I had never seen before, where a class method invocation is used to define nested class methods.

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  class ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.acts_as_paranoid(options={})
      define_model_callbacks :restore, :real_destroy

      alias_method :really_destroyed?, :destroyed?
      alias_method :really_delete, :delete
      alias_method :destroy_without_paranoia, :destroy

      include Paranoia
      class_attribute :paranoia_column, :paranoia_sentinel_value

      self.paranoia_column = (options[:column] || :deleted_at).to_s
      self.paranoia_sentinel_value = options.fetch(:sentinel_value) { Paranoia.default_sentinel_value }

      # This is the line that caught my eye
      def self.paranoia_scope
        where(paranoia_column => paranoia_sentinel_value)
      end

      class << self; alias_method :without_deleted, :paranoia_scope end

      unless options[:without_default_scope]
        default_scope { paranoia_scope }
      end

      (...)
    end
  end
end
```

Ruby [doesn't really have any nested methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864191/is-it-possible-to-have-methods-inside-methods), so what that class method is doing is running code on the context of the class to define other class methods, class_attributes and even include the Paranoia module.

This is very unusual for me, so I'd like to know (1) if that's standard ruby idiom/pattern or my impression that it's unusual is correct and (2) what would be the idiomatic way of achieving that result? (maybe using `class_eval`)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "nested methods". Ultimately you're calling a bunch of stuff, some of which defines methods or variables. You could use `class_eval`, but in the end, does it really matter?

Comment: E.g., see things like https://stackoverflow.com/a/900508/438992 and so on.

Comment: @DaveNewton By nested methods, I mean that the `def self.acts_as_paranoid` (which is a method definition) contains another method definition (`def self.paranoia_scope`)